# How do I split a string in batch after the last "/"?

Tags: string, batch-file, for-loop

I am making a little program for a coding club and some friends and it is like an offline database. I need to put in a dir path (ex. C:\Users\My.Name\Desktop\txtfile.txt) and I need to know how to set these variables -

```
Set Input = C:\Users\My.Name\Desktop\txtfile.txt

REM (SPLIT THE LINE HERE)
REM Output - 

Set Path = C:\Users\My.Name\Desktop
Set Identifier = txtfile.txt
```

How would I do this, I have tried seperating at every "/" but I don't know that there will always be a certain amount of slashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal

Set "Input=C:\Users\My.Name\Desktop\txtfile.txt"

for /f %%a in ("%Input%") do ( 
  echo %%~dpa
  echo %%~nxa
)
```

`For` has nice builtin parameters for splitting paths. Read `FOR /?` at the very end for details. Don't use PATH as a variable. It's a builtin environment variable. I usually use sPath or something similar.